# EF doesn't saving foreign data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys

Table `Contact` have `*→1` relation to table `Location` via `Location ID` key. 
Following code saving all `Contact` data except `Location`. 
What I'm doing wrong? EF 6.0.0.0, MVC 5.2.3.0, but EF 4.4 and MVC 4 also causes this error.

```
using(MyEntities me = new MyEntities())
{
  Contact ct = me.Contact.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.User.UserID == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
  ct.Title = "sometitle"; //assignment and saving works
  ct.Location = me.Location.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Location_ID == 19); //only assignment works
  me.SaveChanges();
}
```

I've disabled direct using of foreign keys when created EDMX model from database due to some errors.

---

Update: both `Contact` and `Location` have relation to `User` by `UserID`. Can this be source of the problem?

Comment: Can you share your fluent or attribute based mapping code along with your entity definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify that Location level must be include in the context to be saved at the end.

So just add .Include("Location") in your code like this

```
using(MyEntities me = new MyEntities())
{
    Contact ct = me.Contact.Include("Location").SingleOrDefault(x=>x.User.UserID == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
    ct.Titile = "sometitle"; //assignment and saving works
    ct.Location = me.Location.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Location_ID == 19); //only assignment works
    me.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Good one, but doesn't helps.

Comment: Location data always missed ? Normally, it will be sufficient to allow context to save subitem of your object. What is the result ?

Comment: Thank thou, Dark Tiger.
I'm used `.Include()` in few more places, from which data comes and problem solved now.
Without `Include()` I has a deal with manually initialization inside context-open window and it's raised some errors, which in the end becomes **ONE BIG DAMNED ERROR**. 
It's really curious, but two years ago I've also had problems like this and solved them with `Include()`.  Human mind is unreliable thing. 
Thanks again.